# Eclipse RSE and xdebug - will this work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xdebug

I have a remote server connected over SSH using the RSE plugin in Eclipse Galileo. Is there anyway to "map" it to a PHP Debug session in Eclipse?

(Xdebug is installed and working)

I have heard that another solution is SSHFS but this might be tricky as I'm on WinXP and would prefer a 'generic' Eclipse solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. RSE will not work with PHP Debugger. This *might* change in Eclipse Halios but I've not moved to Halios yet. The most common solution for Windows seems to be a virtual machine and share a samba mount of the remote webserver between the host and client. Not tried that yet either!

Answer (score 0):

or i imported remote server through RSE so you can debug the remote server when you have the same copy locally. then whenever needed, i edit the local php files and they copy it from eclipse, got RSE, paste it there (overwrite).
it's a pain that RSE does not auto sync.

Comment: So you debug a local copy and paste changes through RSE, right? I do something similar and use Beyond Compare to sync the changes.